# Uncaught ReferenceError: ___ is not defined - typescript

Tags: typescript, antlr, antlr4

I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: ___ is not defined" in typescript at runtime even though the class is defined in the same file and exported. Please guide.

[image: error in browser console]

[image]

[image]

Update : I was able to fix this issue by changing the order of exported class. That means I defined ExpressionContext class before it's used. It's a dirty way since it's a generated code and I don't want to touch it. I would like to understand why it's failing.

Comment: Where is `ExpressionContext` defined. Make sure it is above the consuming code or import it from another module

Comment: It's defined in the same file where the error is occurring.

Comment: It should be defined first. Better to import it

Comment: This is a generated code from a 3rd party library and it's working for many people. I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: Do they use decorators?

Comment: Yes and this 3rd party library is transpiled to Es6/ES2015.

Comment: Can you show a full example using **text** instead of screenshots so that it can be tested?

Comment: Sorry it's difficult for me to copy code here because it's a lot of code. But I have a link to a git repo (not mine) where same 3rd party library is used and it's generated code is sitting here https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr-graps/blob/master/parser/ANTLRv4Parser.ts . If you go to line 5216 , there is a class ElementContext and it's used within same file. This class is also exported so it should be visible. This works for this guy but it's giving me error.